# Ninject MVC and static Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

Hello i am having some problems parsing along my database context to my static helper classes.
For an example my UserHelper class, where i would like to do some lookup to see if the user is an admin.
Right now i fix they by creating a new Context in my Userhelper, but i would like to use the one instance that is created through ninject. How is this possible?

```
public static class UserHelper
{
    private static MetropolOpgavebankenEntities _context;
    public static MetropolOpgavebankenEntities Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (_context == null)
                _context =
                    new MetropolOpgavebankenEntities(
                        ConfigurationManager.Instance.Configuration.ConnectionString.Value);
            return _context;
        }
    }

    public static bool IsAdmin()
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;
        string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        if(Context.Administrators.Any(x => x.MetropolId.ToLower() == username.ToLower()))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

My ninject code

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<MetropolOpgavebankenEntities>().ToMethod(c => new MetropolOpgavebankenEntities(ConfigurationManager.Instance.Configuration.ConnectionString.Value)).InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<OpgavebankService>().To<OpgavebankService>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is this possible?

You should not use static classes. If you want to use dependency injection and have your DI framework handle the lifetime of the objects you should delegate this to it. Otherwise you are no longer using Dependency injection but Service Locator (which is considered as an anti-pattern).

Comment: Then how would you do helpers in asp.net mvc with dependency injection?

Comment: What dependencies do you want to inject into helpers? Helpers are not supposed to be querying databases or so. In ASP.NET MVC HTML helpers are supposed to generate small fragments of HTML code that will be used in the view. The information they are generating this HTML upon is the view model which should contain everything necessary. The view model is populated by the controller which in turn has all necessary dependencies being injected.

Comment: I use my helper for an example to check if an user is an admin.

Comment: That's not something that the helper should be doing. The helper should be using an `IsAdmin` boolean property of the view model that will be calculated in the controller that served the view.

Comment: Sounds like you're coming from a Ruby on Rails background. With the helpers being used like that.

Comment: This is still not helping.. i should have done.. yes... but i am not alone on the project and this is once how it have been made! My question still stands, how can i inject into a static class?

Comment: @DoomStone, you can't do that, sorry. You could violate good practices and use the Service Locator pattern to retrieve the dependency through the DependencyResolver: `var myDependency = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMyDependency>();` in your static class. But as I already mentioned in my answer this pattern is considered anti-pattern.